# duplicate values in cant given error message ,Text Box to add ListBox values

Tags: asp.net

I'm write the Code Text Box to add List Box Values. I want to give the display error for duplicated additions, but this doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                  AddToList();
                  lstValue.Items.Remove("");
                }
```

---

```
private void AddToList()
    {
      if (lstValue.Items.Count > 0)
      {
        txtQlt.Text = txtQlt.Text + "," + cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();
      }
      else
      {
        txtQlt.Text = cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();
      }

      ListItem itm = new ListItem();
      itm.Value = cmbQualityRef.SelectedValue;
      itm.Text = cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();
      if (itm != null)
      {
        lblMsg.Text = "Selected Item Already Exists In The List.";
        return;
      }
      lstValue.Items.Add(itm);
      lstValue.Items.Remove("");

    }
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use items.Contains and check for the string.  This is from assigning itm values and down your function.

```
private void AddToList()
{

  if (lstValue.Items.FindByText(cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString()) == null)
  {
    if (lstValue.Items.Count > 0)
    {
       txtQlt.Text = txtQlt.Text + "," + cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
       txtQlt.Text = cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
   ListItem itm = new ListItem();
   itm.Value = cmbQualityRef.SelectedValue;
   itm.Text = cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();

   lstValue.Items.Add(itm);
  }
  else
  {
     lblMsg.Text = "Selected Item Already Exists In The List.";
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited it from my laptop.  I know that code works, it's a slightly edited version of something I use in one of my current projects.

Comment: You'd just do that check right before you add anything to your lstValue.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the problem, then.  This code should just be used to check to see if the item you're trying to add already exists.
If it is still letting you add it, I'm thinking that your definition of the itm object is probably not matching whatever you're trying to assign it to.  
I'm also not really sure why you'd remove an item from the list right after you add one.  It probably shouldn't need that step.

Comment: When you run this code, does it execute and add the item to your list?  It's just adding duplicates, correct?

Comment: yeah, I want to give the display error for duplicated additions, but this doesn't work

Comment: i think problem is this code part `if (itm != null)
  {
    lblMsg.Text = "Selected Item Already Exists In The List.";
    return;
  }`

Comment: Yeah that doesn't look to be necessary.  I'm working on editing my answer to use exact code.

Comment: actually  your code is work for 99% but  Im add the list box  to item  its cant add the duplicate list box to text box i can add duplicate

Comment: I see something that might help here.  I am editing my code again, using edited code from the guy's answer above me.  I think he may have implemented something a little bit incorrectly, but, FindByText might be the way to go.

Comment: Sir , finally im change your code for some little , now its work  `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("String is already present");` im remove it

Comment: Sir Thank you for the help, :)

Comment: Any time.  I think the issue was just checking for the whole itm object, rather than just the text we're trying to add.

Comment: actually , i got your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

you check list using below code sample

```
 private void AddToList()
    {
        if (lstValue.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            txtQlt.Text = txtQlt.Text + "," + cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            txtQlt.Text = cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }



        if (lstValue.Items.FindByText(txtQlt.Text.ToString()) != null)
        {
            //record is present in list and you code for msg
            lblMsg.Text = "Selected Item Already Exists In The List.";
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            ListItem itm = new ListItem();
            itm.Value = cmbQualityRef.SelectedValue;
            itm.Text = cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();                
            lstValue.Items.Add(itm);
            lstValue.Items.Remove("");
        }



    }
```

where lstValue is id of ListBox

Comment: text Box ID = `cmbQualityRef`

Comment: you need to move  your below code in else part                                              ListItem itm = new ListItem();
  itm.Value = cmbQualityRef.SelectedValue;
  itm.Text = cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString();

  lstValue.Items.Add(itm);
  lstValue.Items.Remove("");

Comment: still not work  :(   ` else { 
                ListItem itm = new ListItem(); 
                itm.Value = cmbQualityRef.SelectedValue;
                itm.Text = cmbQualityRef.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
                lstValue.Items.Add(itm); lstValue.Items.Remove(""); 
            }`

Comment: still i can adding the duplicate values